# No Value given for 1 or more required parameters. Update SQL

Tags: sql, vb.net

I am writing a program that updates the Password or Points when a user selects a record on listview. I get an error "No Value given for 1 or more required parameters" that I do not know how to rectify, am I missing something obvious?

```vb
Dim sql As String = "UPDATE Users SET [Password] = @2,[LoyaltyPoints] = @3 WHERE [Username] = '" & mListView.SelectedItems(0).Text & "'"
cmd = New OleDbCommand(sql, con)

'ADD PARAMETER
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@1", UpdatedUser)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@2", UpdatedPass)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@3", UpdatedPoints)


'OPEN CONNECTION,EXECUTE UPDATE,CLOSE CONNECTION'
Try
    con.Open()
    adapter = New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)
    adapter.UpdateCommand = con.CreateCommand()
    adapter.UpdateCommand.CommandText = sql

    If (adapter.UpdateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() = 0) Then 'Error Appears Here
        MsgBox("Successfully Updated")
        ClearAll()
    Else
        MsgBox("Unsuccessful")
     End If
     con.Close()
     Retrieve()

     Catch ex As Exception
         MsgBox(ex.Message)
         con.Close()
     End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you show where you're getting your values for UpdatedUser/Pass/Points?

Comment: Your code is still open to being hacked with sql injection.  You should parameterize your user name as well.

Comment: ```        UpdatePass = edtUpdatePass.Text
        If UpdatePass = Nothing Then
            MsgBox("Please ensure the whole form is completed", MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
        ElseIf Val(edtUpdatePoints.Text) = 0 Then
            MsgBox("Base Loyalty Points Must be a Number", MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
        End If
        UpdatePoints = edtUpdatePoints.Text

       UpdateLV(sSelectedUser, UpdatePass, UpdatePoints)
        End If
``` where I get my variables

Comment: I'm pretty sure that a parameter name can't start with a number: `@1` = fail, `@p1` = success. Also, although using SQL parameters is correct, please take note of [AddWithValue is Evil](https://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/), [AddWithValue is evil!](http://chrisrickard.blogspot.com/2007/06/addwithvalue-is-evil.html) and [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/).

Comment: @AndrewMorton I get the same error if I replace the parameter names to "@P1", "@P2" and "@P3", what should I use instead of AddWithValue()?

Comment: @KeyandeKlerk Did you remember to change the names in the query *and* the parameters? You can use, e.g. `cmd.Parameters.Add("@P1", OleDbType.Integer).Value = UpdatedPoints` to make sure that the correct data type is used.

Comment: @AndrewMorton I tried `cmd.Parameters.Add("@P1",OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = UpdatedUser` but no success, all the values are string

Comment: It throws this error Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' in System.Windows.Forms.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' in System.Data.dll

Comment: @KeyandeKlerk You should probably add the parameters in the order that they appear in the query - I don't think OleDb necessarily uses the names, they are more to remind the programmer what they are for.

Comment: @KeyandeKlerk What does the `Retrieve()` method do?

Comment: Why are you creating a data adapter that you're not even using? If you're not calling `Fill` and `Update`, there's no reason to be using a data adapter.

Comment: @andrewMorton the `retrieve()` method is for selecting all the database contents and to fill the listview I am using as a display

Answer (score 0):

Others have already pointed out the issue (and the solution), but I want to add one thing...  avoid naming parameters 1, 2, 3 or A, B, C.  I'll bet a donut that if you named them in a way that corresponds to the data being sent, it would have been easier to diagnose the issue.  You were missing @1 in your query...  but don't name it @1:

```
Dim sql As String = "UPDATE Users SET [Password] = @PASS,[LoyaltyPoints] = @POINTS WHERE [Username] = @USER"
cmd = New OleDbCommand(sql, con)

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@USER", UpdatedUser)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PASS", UpdatedPass)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@POINTS", UpdatedPoints)
```

And not to rub salt in the wound, but your solution is a big step backwards.  Parameters are good all around.  They are better for the database, cleaner code, completely safe, and they handle data weirdness, for example if there are single quote characters in any of the values you are passing (your solution will crash if that happens).

Comment: Even copying the provided code, I still receive the same error "No Value given for one or more required parameters"

Comment: Are any of your three variables (UpdatedUser, UpdatedPass, UpdatedPoints) null?

Comment: It throws an error at `adapter.UpdateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery` at that point all 3 variables have assigned values

Comment: You need to add the parameters to the command in the same order they appear in the SQL.

Comment: so like `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PASS", UpdatedPass)`
        `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@POINTS", UpdatedPoints)`
        `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@USER", UpdatedUser)` If so, it throws the same error

Comment: I don't know if this matters in SQL Server or not (I assume this is SQL Server -- I primarily use PostgreSQL and Oracle), but in Oracle it insists on setting the `BindByName` property on the command object to true.  Postgres doesn't care.  Can you post the DDL?  I'm at the point where I'd like to test this for myself.  This *should* work.

Comment: @Hambone The `OleDbCommand` suggests that it is using Access rather than SQL Server.

Comment: @AndrewMorton -- Aaah, that helps a lot.  Never occurred to me.  I've seen OLE used across multiple DBMSs, but Access never even crossed my mind

Answer (score 0):

The code should work like this:

```vb
Dim updatedUser = mListView.SelectedItems(0).Text

Dim sql As String = "UPDATE Users SET [Password] = @pass, [LoyaltyPoints] = @points WHERE [Username] = @username"

Using conn As New OleDbConnection("your connection string"),
        cmd As New OleDbCommand(sql, conn)

    'TODO: Use the correct values for each .OleDbType and .Size parameter.
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter With {.ParameterName = "@pass", .OleDbType = OleDbType.VarWChar, .Size = 99, .Value = updatedPass})
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter With {.ParameterName = "@points", .OleDbType = OleDbType.Integer, .Value = updatedPoints})
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter With {.ParameterName = "@username", .OleDbType = OleDbType.VarWChar, .Size = 99, .Value = updatedUser})

    Try
        conn.Open()

        If cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() = 0 Then
            MsgBox("Unsuccessful")
            ClearAll()
        Else
            MsgBox("Successfully Updated")
        End If

        Retrieve()

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try

End Using
```

Comment: @KeyandeKlerk You're welcome :) In case you weren't aware: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)