# Shows Error Conversion from String to type Double is not Valid, Input String is not in correct Format

Tags: vb.net

**Following are my codes Pls Help me**

1. I found this error on updating the Table

```
Private Sub UpdateInventory()

    Dim connectionString As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("MainConString").ConnectionString
    Dim con As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
    Dim Query1 As String

    Try
        Dim Result As DialogResult
        Result = MessageBox.Show(" Update this Record ?", "Save ! ", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question)
        If Result = DialogResult.Yes Then
            For J As Integer = 0 To DataGridStock.Rows.Count - 1 Step +1
                Query1 = "Update Tempstock Set Type='" & LabelTrancode.Text & "', Prefix='" & Lblprefix.Text & "', Srl='" & TextINVNo.Text & "', 
                          DOcDate='" & TextBoxdocdate.Text & "',Sno='" & DataGridStock.Rows(J).Cells(0).Value & "', Hsncode='" & DataGridStock.Rows(J).Cells(4).Value & "',
                          Branch='" & LBLBranchcode.Text & "',Taxcode='" & DataGridStock.Rows(J).Cells(5).Value & "',Code='" & DataGridStock.Rows(J).Cells(2).Value & "',
                          Qty='" + (DataGridStock.Rows(J).Cells(6).Value) + "',Rate='" + Int(DataGridStock.Rows(J).Cells(8).Value) + "',Unit='" & DataGridStock.Rows(J).Cells(7).Value & "'"
                Dim query = String.Concat(Query1, ";")
                con.Open()

                cmd = New SqlCommand(query, con)
                reader = cmd.ExecuteReader
                reader.Close()
                con.Close()


            Next
            MessageBox.Show(" Stock Updated")
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: 1) You should use SQL parameters to pass the values - do not use string concatenation to put the values into the query string. 2) There is no "WHERE" in the query, so it does not know which record to update. 3) It should be `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery`, not `cmd.ExecuteReader`.

Comment: Here is an example of using SQL parameters with an UPDATE statement: [No Value given for 1 or more required parameters. Update SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60210748/1115360) - you just need to write `Sql` where it has `OleDb`, e.g. `OleDbConnection` -> `SqlConnection`.

Comment: And if the process of using SQL parameters doesn't fix it, please see the "Related" section on this page down on the right.